# Proper way to Navigate from a List page to Detail Page (vice-versa)

Tags: jsf, navigation, master-detail

I was trying to find some proper way to navigate from List to Detail page
My list.page uses list.bean(`viewscoped`)
and my detail.page uses detail.bean(`Viewscoped` too)
From list.page I did test two ways to go to detail.page
1) navigation rule (without redirect)
2) redirect link (specifying the parameters on URL)

My questions and issues is
1) what is is the proper way to go from list.page to detail.page
2) Is that possible to return to list.page keeping the last result(result shown before i go to detail.page) actually when I return to list.page it shown a blank list.page?

Comment: Why your list page is blank? are you loading data on postconstruct?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find how to return to list.page wihtout loosing the last results